# html/javascript scripting problems

Tags: javascript, html, function, button, web

I testing out some things, combining html and javascript. Right now I'm trying to make a button do something when the user clicks it.

Fx

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() 
{
confirm ("Welcome!");
}
</script>
</head>
```

Plus the button:

```
 <body> 
 <button onclick="popup()">Try it</button>
 </body>
```

This works out very well and the popup windows appears. Now when I for example want to print a line when clicking the button, I'm just replacing "confirm" with "console.log", wich doesnt work...

What am i doing wrong, and how would i make the button print a simple line of text?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Press F12 and click on the console tab.

There you'll be able to see the result.

`console.log()` is used for debug purpose and logging purpose. It is not used for pronting a line.

Comment: Alright, so console.log is only "behind the scenes" and only seen in the console. Okay, how would I be able to print a line by clicking the button? Do I need another language for that, fx php??

Comment: use `document.write("Hi");` for learning purpose. By the way don't forget to accept my answer :)

Answer (score 1):

console.log is for debugging.
To print something on page, use

```
<head> 
<script type="text/javascript">
function popup() 
{
document.getElementById("div").innerHTML="Welcome!"
}
</script>
</head>
<body> 
 <button onclick="popup()">Try it</button>
 <div id="div"></div>
 </body>
```

Answer (score 1):

I reccomend you use a DOM manipulation library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) to avoid setting events and behaviors manually.

This means doing something like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function() {
                jQuery('#mybutton').click(function() {
                    jQuery('#mytext').append('This is a line of text');
                });
            });
       </script>
    </head>
    <body> 
         <button id="mybutton">Try it</button>
            <div id="mytext"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

I took your question literally. This will append text to the DOM. Logging to console has no effect on the DOM, but at is was already said, you can inspect it with F12.